# Mutual TLS support in mbed-TLS

Tags: c, embedded, mtls, mbedtls

I've been looking for examples of mutual TLS support using mbed-TLS but have not found anything. Does anyone know or have experience with this before? Especially in embedded systems?

Thanks

Looking for example usage of mbed-TLS in context of mutual TLS.

Comment: Are you talking about mutual authentication?  Where the server authenticates to the client (always), and the client also must authenticate to the server?